# Updating GitLab page, HAML script

Tags: gitlab, haml

I need to extend GitLab a little bit and add a link on one of its pages. I found a HAML script (`_tree_header.html.haml`) and added the following line there:

```
 = link_to _('My Label'), "http://localhost:8080/myapp"(start: 'A'), class: 'btn'
```

I want it to be converted to:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/myapp?start='A'">My Label</a>
```

However I am getting an error:

> "error":"SyntaxError: /opt/oraclebase/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/projects/tree/_tree_header.html.haml:22: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ')'\n  syntax error, unexpected tLABEL\n

I looked at some HAML tutorials but couldn't find clear description on how to add parameters to the link.

Comment: Show the full code, or at least link to the original one you started from.

Comment: here is an original code that works : = link_to _('My Label'), "localhost:8080/myapp", class: 'btn' – vs777